# Python : Running a loop during a precise duration

Tags: python, time

I need to run a loop during a precise duration. For example, the code I'm trying to make would look like that :

```
initialize and lauch timer

while timer<10000sec:
   do things
```

Do you know how to do this ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Should `do things` be *aborted* after given time or should it finish first?

Comment: The whole "Do thing" have to be done, so it must not be aborted at the end of the timer.

Comment: Just how precise do you have to be, and why?

Comment: I have to be precise around the second (plus the time of an occurence of the loop). This code is made to test the capacity of a server, so the precision is not critical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
stop = time.time()+10000
while time.time() < stop:
  do things
```

This requires that each run through the loop is sufficiently short so that you read the current time often enough (for the preciseness that you want to achieve).

Comment: on the other hand if the loop body is very short the call to `time.time()` on each iteration can dominate the runtime. What I'm trying to say to the OP is that if performance is critical here, he may consider an alternative approach

Comment: This code works perfectly. But I'd like a method less power consuming if it exists.

Comment: @Nix: you'll have to explain what "do things" actually is. In good programming, you should be blocking when you wait for something to happen, instead of polling: this (bad) approach is called "busy wait". If you need busy wait, you can put calls of time.sleep(delay) into the loop, with delay being e.g. 0.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

t_end = time.time() + 60 * <> #duration goes inside <>; eg 2 for 2 minutes

while time.time() < t_end:

   #rest of the code
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?